# How to get specific strings between strings in rows?

Tags: pandas, split

I have a df like this:

```
Radiosoundings From Brazil
5   #  TEMP/PILOT de 82022, Boa Vista, Boa Vista Intl  (Brazil) | 02-50N | 060-42W | 84 m 
59  #  TEMP/PILOT de 82026, Tirios (Brazil) | 02-29N | 055-59W | 325 m 
108 #  TEMP/PILOT de 82099, Macapa-Aeroporto (Brazil) | 00-03N | 051-04W | 16 m 
192 #  TEMP/PILOT de 82107, Sao Gabriel Da Cachoeira (Aero) (Brazil) | 00-07S | 066-58W | 79 m 
255 #  TEMP/PILOT de 82193, Belem Aeroporto  (Brazil) | 01-23S | 048-29W | 16 m 
332 #  TEMP/PILOT de 82244, Santarem-Aeroporto (Brazil) | 02-26S | 054-43W | 72 m 
408 #  TEMP/PILOT de 82281, Sao Luiz Aeroporto  (Brazil) | 02-36S | 044-14W | 53 m 
479 #  TEMP/PILOT de 82332, Manaus Aeroporto  (Brazil) | 03-09S | 059-59W | 84 m 
547 #  TEMP/PILOT de 82397, Fortaleza (Brazil) | 03-46S | 038-36W | 26 m
```

I want to get only the latitude longitude and the code of each row.
Example:

```
Code  Lat    Lon 
82022 02-50N 060-42W
```

How can i do this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) with a combination of [str extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [rsplit](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) could help: try this and confirm it works for all cases:

```
df['code'] = df[1].str.extract(r'((?<=TEMP/PILOT de\s)\d+)')
df['lon'] = df[1].str.rsplit('|').str[2]
df['lat'] = df[1].str.rsplit('|').str[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
df['Code']=df[1].str.extract('((\d+)(?=\,\s))')[0]
df['Lat']=df[1].str.extract('(\d+\-\d+[N|S]+)')[0]
df['Long']=df[1].str.extract('(\d+\-\d+[E|W]+)')[0]
```

`\d+)(?=\,\s`- Any digit immediately followed by space and coma

`\d+\-\d+[N|S]+`- digit followed by - and then followed by digit and either N or S

`\d+\-\d+[E|W]+`- digit followed by -and then followed by digit and either E or W